WiFiManager library question (wm.setConfigPortalBlocking(false) + big delay = not working)
I'm trying to use the library in my project. An implementation with wm.setConfigPortalBlocking(false) is needed, but when a large delay is used in the loop, the portal either does not work at all, or it freezes very much and the web interface does not load. What can be done?
For example:
#include <WiFiManager.h>
WiFiManager wm;

void setup() {
    WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA); 
    Serial.begin(9600);
    wm.setConfigPortalBlocking(false);
    if(wm.autoConnect("TEST-AP")){
        Serial.println("connected...yeey :)");
    }
    else {
        Serial.println("Configportal running");
    }
}

void loop() {
    wm.process();
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(60000);
}


examine the blinkWithoutDelay example sketch in the Arduino IDE

Use a shorter delay.
WiFiManager only gets to run when you call wm.process(). When you use a large delay you prevent it from doing any processing during that time, as you saw. This is the way it works. If you want it to work best, don't use a delay at all.

there is no way to get working portal with another lib or code with big delay? am i right?

Why do you think you need a big delay? You almost certainly don't.

because in the loop i sending data from sensors to google script and i need them only once per 60 sec

So you write your loop to send data only one per 60 seconds. You can do other stuff during that time, you don't have to not do anything for 60 seconds.
